# Trying to port a game to Linux, calling XInitThreads gets me a syntax error

Tags: c++, linux, x11

Here's how the offending line looks like in the code:

```
#ifdef SFML_SYSTEM_LINUX
    XInitThreads();
#endif
```

I've invoked the requisite libraries at the beginning of the code as follows:

```
#ifdef SFML_SYSTEM_LINUX
    #include <X11/Xlib.h>;
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <pwd.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
#endif
```

It gives me this error in Code::Blocks:

> error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘;’ token

This error references line 111 in the code, which is the XInitThreads call in the first function I quoted above.

Am I missing something? I've tried setting the linker to include the X11 library, but so far it hasn't changed anything.

EDIT: Here's more code from the beginning of game.cpp - http://pastebin.com/7D2WLRM7

Comment: Try removing the `;` after `#include <X11/Xlib.h>`.

Comment: @tuple_cat Thanks, removed that, but it didn't change anything. I forgot to mention that the error is in reference to the "XInitThreads();" call in the first function I quoted in my question. I'll edit the question itself to be more clear about that.

Comment: @andoru: give us more code around `XInitThreads`

Comment: We don't have a way to reproduce this problem. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and adjust your Q so we can help. Good luck.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak I added more code from the beginning of the file. It's a personal project of mine, so I don't want to reveal more than it's necessary, although of course more is needed to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @andoru, please try to prepare *minimal* example that reproduces your problem and include it directly into your question. This way, people can easily try it and help.

Comment: @gavv Just did that, thanks.

Comment: @andoru, do you mean pastbin link? There are two problems with it: 1) it's far from minimal 2) external links to code are not encouraged, try to prepare short example and include it *directly* into the question body next time (see discussion [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271914/is-there-a-description-of-the-policy-for-links-in-posts)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to "call" this function outside of any function or method block.

Your compiler can't understand what you're trying to do. Move these lines into Game::Init perhaps?

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem, now onto more debugging :D